# Second harmonic of Josephoson current

Tags: superconductivity, perturbation-theory, greens-functions, josephson-junction

The expression of Josephson current including the second harmonic between two s-wave superconductors is
$$ I_{J}=I_{1}sin(\phi)+I_{2}sin(2\phi) $$
I try to calculate $I_{2}$ by following derivation in Section 18.7 Bruus & Flensberg.

The Hamilitonian is
$H=H_{0}+H_{t}$.
$H_{0}$ is unperturbed Hamilitonian and is made out of mean-field BCS Hamilitonians of left and right superconductors. $H_{t}$ is the tunneling Hamilitonian.
$$H_{t}=\sum_{k,p,\alpha} t(k,p)c_{k,\alpha}^{\dagger}f_{p,\alpha}+h.c$$
$k$ and $p$ are momentum indices. $\alpha$ is spin index. $c^{\dagger}$ ($f^{\dagger}$) and $c$ ($f$) are electron creation and annihilation operators of left (right) superconductor.

Now the definition of Josephson current is
$$I_{J} = -e\langle \dot{N_{c}}\rangle=-e\langle \frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi} \rangle $$
$N_{c}$ is the number operator of left superconductor and $\phi$ is phase difference between two superconductors. Now I evaluate $\langle \frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi} \rangle$ in the interaction picture with imagnary time and expand in powers of $t(k,p)$, I have
$$\large \langle \frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi}\rangle=\frac{Tr(e^{-\beta H_{0}}T_{\tau}(e^{-\int_{0}^{\beta} H_{t}(\tau) \,d\tau})\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi})}{Tr(e^{-\beta H_{0}}T_{\tau}(e^{-\int_{0}^{\beta} H_{t}(\tau) \,d\tau}))}=\frac{Tr(e^{-\beta H_{0}}(H_{t}^{1}+H_{t}^{3})\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi})}{Tr(e^{-\beta H_{0}}(1+H_{t}^{2}))} $$
$T_{\tau}$ is time-ordering operator. I throw away any odd power of $H_{t}$ (no contribution).
For calculating $I_{2}$, I only need terms with fourth order in $t(k,p)$, I have
$\langle H_{t}^{3}\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi}\rangle_{0}-\langle H_{t}^{1}\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi}\rangle_{0}\langle H_{t}^{2}\rangle_{0}$
($\langle \, \rangle_{0}$ means evaluating expectation value in unperturbed Hamilitonian). $H_{t}^{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{\beta}...\int_{0}^{\beta} T_{\tau}(H_{t}(\tau_{1})...H_{t}(\tau_{n}) )\,d\tau_{1}...d\tau_{n}$. Then
$$\langle H_{t}^{3}\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi}\rangle_{0}=\frac{(-1)}{6}\int_{0}^{\beta}...\int_{0}^{\beta} \langle T_{\tau}(H_{t}(\tau_{1})...H_{t}(\tau_{3})\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi})\rangle_{0} \,d\tau_{1}...d\tau_{3}
$$
Next I use wick theorem and collect equivalent terms, I have
$$\langle H_{t}^{3}\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi}\rangle_{0}=\frac{(-1)}{2}\int_{0}^{\beta}...\int_{0}^{\beta} \langle T_{\tau}(H_{t}(\tau_{1})H_{t}(\tau_{2}))\rangle_{0} \langle T_{\tau}(H_{t}(\tau_{3})\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi})\rangle_{0} \,d\tau_{1}...d\tau_{3}$$
This is equivalent to $\langle H_{t}^{1}\frac{dH_{t}}{d\phi}\rangle_{0}\langle H_{t}^{2}\rangle_{0}$. It gives $I_{2}=0$.
This makes me feel that all higher order harmonics are vanishing in perturbation theory (only first order term survives)
I am wondering if there is any mistake I made in the above derivation. I am greatly appreciated if someone could help me or enlighten me in some way. Thank you ！！！